# Adding city name in front of branch datetimes

Tags: python, datetime

I have three branch locations with the times in respect to their cities, however, I don't know how to write the names of the cities in front of the times. Would someone please help me?

Thanks

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

portland_time = datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC).replace(microsecond=0)
Portland = portland_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))

new_york_time = portland_time.astimezone(timezone('US/Eastern'))
Ny = new_york_time

london_time = portland_time.astimezone(timezone('Europe/London'))
London = london_time

cities = {'Portland': Portland,
          'Ny': Ny,
          'London': London}

def branches():
    for city in cities:
        Branchtime=int(cities[city].strftime('%H'))
        if Branchtime >= 9 and Branchtime < 21:
            print(city, cities[city], 'OPEN')
        else:
            print(city, cities[city], 'CLOSED')
branches()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind using a `dict` instead of a `list` for your `cities`? If not you can do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

portland_time = datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC).replace(microsecond=0)
Portland = portland_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))

new_york_time = portland_time.astimezone(timezone('US/Eastern'))
Ny = new_york_time

london_time = portland_time.astimezone(timezone('Europe/London'))
London = london_time

cities = {'Portland': Portland, 
          'Ny': Ny, 
          'London': London}

for city in cities:
    Branchtime=int(cities[city].strftime('%H'))
    if Branchtime >= 9 and Branchtime < 21:
        print(city, cities[city], 'OPEN')
    else:
        print(city, cities[city], 'CLOSED')
```

Gives you:

```
Ny 2017-06-10 02:22:55-04:00 CLOSED
Portland 2017-06-09 23:22:55-07:00 CLOSED
London 2017-06-10 07:22:55+01:00 CLOSED
```